# how to create a json array in swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, object

I am trying to send a POST http request with the following in Swift and struggling to find out how to write the 'params' part below into Swift.

```
{ 
"method": "getContentCount", 
"params": [
   { "uri": "storage:memoryCard1", 
   "target": "all" }
  ]
}
```

As for the 'param', I think its json array with just one item in it and tried

`a) params: ["scheme":"storage"]`
// I assume this is a json object and doesn't match with the above 'params' format  and it doesn't work

`b) params: [ ["uri": "storage:memoryCard1", "target": "all" ]]` I assume this is the right one to match with the 'params' but this doesn't work either.

I have search for an answer on Stackoverflow to little avail. If you know the answer or any reference to the answer, please leave a comment.

I appreciate your time for reading this.

Comment: It's an array of dictionaries where the dictionary has two key/value pairs. How are you creating your json in code? Share that and it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use [] twice. `params: ["uri": "storage:memoryCard1", "target": "all" ]`